# Numpy: Meshgrid vs ix_

Tags: numpy

From the look of it, both `numpy.meshgrid` and `numpy.ix_` seem to do pretty much the same. Is there a significant difference between them, or is the other just a convenient shortcut?

Comment: These two functions do not do the same thing! Try calling `numpy.meshgrid([1,2],[3,4])` and `numpy.ix_([1,2],[3,4])`.

Comment: So, what does the name `ix` stands for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

numpy.meshgrid is 2-Dimensional.

numpy.ix_ is n-dimensional.

Comment: it is now [multidimensional](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html).